# Is there a native reset event for new HTML5 input types?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Some HTML5 input types bring native reset buttons by default. E.g. `<input type="date">` has this little x icon to remove former selection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

I wonder if there is no native JS event I can rely on? By now I have implemented a change listener that checks if the value is empty, but this doesn't feel to be correct.

Comment: Is the listener not working? Share your codes

Comment: My bad, may I ask you to rephrase your question since I am not clear about the things you are trying to do? What are the issues you are facing exactly?

Comment: @rags2riches I believe what he wants is an event listener that listens for when an input element resets. Eg something like `$('input').on('reset', function(){})`

Comment: @dilanMD my onchange listener is working without any problems. I am not facing any real issues here. As TKoL has written I am wondering if there isn't any nicer implementation to check if a user has used the native reset button.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `<input type="date">` inputs, I don't think you're going to find a better solution than setting an onChange callback and checking if the value of the string is empty.

In jQuery, that would look like:

```
$('input#dateinput').on('change', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.value === '') {
    // do your stuff here
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer. I was afraid that there isn't any better solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. The _problem_ is, that the change event is fired for any change - not only for a reset. So I was hoping that there is something like the following:

`$('input#dateinput').on('reset', ...`

Comment: Yes, the change event is fired for any change, but the stuff after the `if()` is only fired when the target value is blank, ie a reset.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly two solutions for this :

1. First one is to use the latest HTML5 input tag of type search, this provides a built-in clear option

   You could use this:

```html
<form>
  <input type='search'placeholder='Please enter something'/>
</form>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/b68zkhne/

2. Use Bootstrap provided input field, that provides a clear option
   https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clear-Button-Bootstrap/